# C++ different behavior between reference and pointer to interface

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, reference, virtual

I was trying to write an interface for a variable value. The base class only provides an `enum` field, where the type of the Variable is stored (like `int`, `char`, etc...) and some virtual functions.
The classes inheriting this interface should implement a representation of a variable type each.

```
#include <iostream>

enum Type
{
    INT, CHAR
};

class Var
{
    Type type;
public:
    Var(Type t):
        type(t)
    {}
    virtual void printValue()
    {
        std::cout << "-\n";
    }
    virtual void printType()
    {
        std::cout << type << std::endl;
    }
};

class IntVar : public Var
{
    int value;
public:
    IntVar(int i):
        Var(INT),
        value(i)
    {}
    void printValue()
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
};

class CharVar : public Var
{
    char value;
public:
    CharVar(char c):
        Var(CHAR),
        value(c)
    {}
    void printValue()
    {
        std::cout << value << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Then I tried this:

```
Var* np = new IntVar(1);

np->printType();
np->printValue();
np = new CharVar('a');
np->printType();
np->printValue();
```

The output was

> 0 (Type::INT), 1, 1 (Type::CHAR), a

so everything worked as expected, but when I tried the same with references, the outcome was a bit strange.

```
Var& nr = *(new IntVar(1));
nr.printType();
nr.printValue();
nr = *(new CharVar('a'));
nr.printType();
nr.printValue();
```

Here the output was

> 0 (Type::INT), 1, 1 (Type::CHAR) and **1**

Why did the code work, when using pointers and didn't work with references? Or do I overlook some obvious errors?

Comment: You are using `new` wrong. Your program has a memory leak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution using pointers makes `nr` point to an `IntVar` at first, and then to a `CharVar`.

The solution using references creates an `IntVar` object, then it creates a new name (`nr`) for that object and then changes the values of this object based on the values of a `CharVar`.

References cannot be rebased as you did with pointers. A reference references the same object throughout its lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
nr = *(new CharVar('a'));
```

is an assignment with a very different meaning than

```
np = new CharVar('a');
```

Section 12.8:

> The implicitly-defined copy/move assignment operator for a non-union
>   class X performs memberwise copy/move assignment of its subobjects.
>   The direct base classes of X are assigned first, in the order of their
>   declaration in the base-specifier-list, and then the immediate
>   non-static data members of X are assigned, in the order in which they
>   were declared in the class definition....

*nr* is using the implicit assignment operator `Var::operator=()` that copies fields from Var. You are not changing the reference type, it is still a reference to an IntVar object.

Answer (score 1):

```
Var& nr = *(new IntVar(1));  //nr are Bound to IntVar object
nr=*(new CharVar('a'));    //replace the base part of IntVar object
                            //  by the base part of CharVar object
```